# Add a mongo document as vertex - Gremlin

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, gremlin

I'm learning to use Gremlin with MongoDB. I want to create a graph neo4j starting from a mongo database, called Project.

```
import com.gmongo.GMongo
gremlin> mongo = new GMongo()
==>com.gmongo.GMongo@5c08c46a
gremlin> db = mongo.getDB("Project")
==>DB{name='Project'}
gremlin> Graph graph = new Neo4jGraph("/tmp/my_graph");
==>neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [\tmp\my_graph]]
```

Now I can use mongo commands on Gremlin shell.

Project database has a collection called *team*. Here is a document of team collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "Juv.35",
    "official_name" : "Juventus Football Club S.p.A.",
    "common_name" : "Juventus",
    "country" : "Italy",
    "started_by" : {
        "day" : 1,
        "month" : 11,
        "year" : 1897
    },
    "stadium" : {
        "name" : "Juventus Stadium",
        "capacity" : 41011
    },
    "palmarès" : {
        "Serie A" : 33,
        "Coppa Italia" : 10,
        "Supercoppa Italiana" : 6,
        "UEFA Champions League" : 3,
        "UEFA Europa League" : 3,
        "UEFA Super Cup" : 2,
        "UEFA Intertoto cup" : 1,
        "Cup Winners cup" : 1,
        "UEFA Intercontinental cup" : 2
    },
    "uniform" : "black and white"
}
```

Now I want to add a vertex to the variable graph that contains information about Juventus.
I try this:

```
gremlin> graph.addVertex([db.team.find({common_name:'Juventus'})])
```

But it does not work. (I'm not able to find documentation about this subject) What can I do to add this vertex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what "does not work" but let me offer the following.  Your syntax for `addVertex` doesn't look quite right.  Forgetting about mongodb for a moment:

```
graph.addVertex(1)
```

adds a vertex with the id specified.  of course, neo4j doesn't support user-supplied ids so that value is ignored.  On the other hand if you call it like this:

```
graph.addVertex([common_name:'Juventus'])
```

where you supply a Groovy `Map` you will create a vertex with the property "common_name" and a value for that property of "Juventus".  With the syntax you have now:

```
graph.addVertex([db.team.find({common_name:'Juventus'})])
```

you are calling addVertex and the argument you are passing is a Groovy `List` of whatever is returned from your mongo db lookup.  I assume that Neo4j is just ignoring that argument all together and why it looks like nothing is working.

Given that your data is nested I think you will have to transform that data a little bit to get it directly into Neo4j (I didn't think that Neo4j supports `Map` as a data type).  So to add a vertex, I think you will want to do something like:

```
transformToMap = { record -> ... }
graph.addVertex(transformToMap(db.team.find({common_name:'Juventus'})))
```

where `transformToMap` is some function that you write that takes that nested structure and flattens it out. So something like this:

```
"stadium" : {
    "name" : "Juventus Stadium",
    "capacity" : 41011
},
```

would turn into "stadium-name" and "stadium-capacity".  With a flattened `Map` i would think that your data should load quite nicely.

Also, you should consider how you will index your data.  As you can not assign identifiers, you will need to create indices so that you can look up your data in a unique way.

Comment: Using a guide I was able to add the team _id as vertex:

`gremlin>  mongo = new GMongo()
==>com.gmongo.GMongo@5c08c46a
gremlin> db = mongo.getDB("Progettino")
==>DB{name='Progettino'}
gremlin> x=[] as Set; db.team.find().each{x.add(it._id)}
gremlin> g = new Neo4jGraph('/tmp/neo4j')
gremlin> x.each{g.addVertex(it)}
gremlin> g.V
==>v[815]
==>v[816]
==>v[817]
==>v[818]
==>v[819]
==>v[820]
==>v[821]`


Now how can I add node's properties?

Comment: Ok, I found how to set a property:
`g.v(819).property='value_property'`

Is it possible there isn't any documentation about this subject?  BHA 
just try, try and try untill the right way.

Comment: ? - i'm not sure what you mean.  there are tons of resources.  how about: [gremlin wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Updating-a-Graph) or http://gremlindocs.com/ or the [javadoc](http://bit.ly/1H95CyA) to name a few